# Threaded Communication and Object Overhead

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, backgroundworker, timing

Denizens of Stack Overflow I require your knowledge.  I am working on a video processing system utilizing WPF and basic C# .NET socket communications.  Each client transmits video data at 30 frames per second to a server across a LAN environment for processing.  Some of the processing is handled by each of the clients to mitigate server load.

I have learned programing in an environment in which hardware limitations have never been a concern.  Video changes that..  "Hello World" did not prepare me for this to say the least.  Implementation of either of these two prospective methods is not a serious issue.  Determination of which I should devote my time and energy to is where I require assistance.

I have two options (but open to suggestions!) assuming hardware limits the clients from producing as close to real time results as possible:

--Queued Client--
Client processes a queue of video frames.  Each frame is processed and then sent via TCP packets to the server for further analysis.  This system only processes a single frame at a time, in order of sensor capture, and transmits it to the server via a static socket client.  *This system fails to take advantage of modern multi-core hardware.

--Threaded Client--
The client utilizes threaded (background worker) processing and transmission of each frame to the server.  Each new frame triggers a new processing thread as well as the instantiation of a new network communication class.  *This system utilizes modern hardware but may produce serious timing concerns.

To the heart of my inquiry, does threaded communication produce mostly-in-order communication?  I already plan to synch video frames between the clients on the server end... but will data delivery be so far out of order as to create a new problem? Recall that this is communication across a local network.

More importantly, will instantiating a new socket communication class as well as a new (simple) video processing class create enough overhead that each frame should NOT be queued or processed in parallel?

The code is just starting to take shape.  Hardware of the client systems is unknown and as such their performance cannot be determined.  How would you proceed with development?

I am a college student. As such any input assists me in the design of my first real world application of my knowledge.

Comment: Please read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx which contains loads of information related to your case. Parallism is perfectly reasonable in your case. Since uploading an image and retrieving it from the source take some considerable amount of time, you can perfectly offload these tasks in their own isolated context (thread). Read the given link and look up the producer/consumer collection which is great in your case for synchronization.

Comment: Pipelining sounds good, and for stages that have execution times of a similar order, it is.  Unfortunately, video streaming and processing often has stages that dominate in terms of CPU loading.  This is effectively a bottleneck - a narrow section of pipe.  Unless this stage can use multiple narrow pipes, the stream will be held up even though there are spare narrow pipes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one valid response to "is performance of XXXXXXX sufficient" - try and measure.

In your case you should estimate

- network traffic to/from server.
- number of clients/number of units of work per unit of time clients send (i.e. total number of frames per second in your case)
- how long processing of a unit of work will take

When you estimate the requirements - see if it looks reasonable (i.e. having 10Tb/second of incoming data can't be handled by any normal machine, while 100Mb/s may work with normal 1Gb network).

Than build most basic version of the system possible (i.e. use ASP.Net to build single page site and post files to it at required speed, for "processing" use Thread.Sleep) and observe/measure results.

As for you "will creation of an object be slow" - extremely unlikely to matter for your case as you plan to send huge amount of data over network. But this is extremely easy to try yourself - StopWatch + `new MyObject()` will show you detailed timing.

Answer (score 1):

'To the heart of my inquiry, does threaded communication produce mostly-in-order communication?'  No, not in general.  If video frames are processed concurrently then some mechanism to maintain end-to-end order is often required, (eg. sequence numbers), together with a suitable protocol and sufficient buffering to reassemble and maintain a valid sequence of frames at the server, (with the correct timing and sychronization, if display is required instead of/as well as streaming to a disk file.

Video usually requires every trick available to optimize performance. Pools of frame objects, (optimally allocated to avoid false-sharing), to avoid garbage-collection, threadPools for image-processing etc.

'will data delivery be so far out of order as to create a new problem?' - quite possibly, if you don't specify and apply a suitable mimimum network speed and availablilty, some streams may stretch the available bufffering to the point where frames have to be dropped, duplicated or interpolated to maintain synchronization.  Doing that effectively is part of the fun of video protocols :)

Comment: Oh - how to proceed with development.  This is a non-trivial battle, so get to know your enemy, and your weapons, first.  Build a test app that generates frame objects from a file at controllable rates.  This is something you will probably need for testing, but is non-deliverable, so you can screw it about until it works well and you then know how to use your object pools, thread pools, P-C queues, frame sequence reassembly vectors etc. etc. before you start on your 'real' client and server.